# Amending a dataset using multiple 'Or' statements to match column data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset consisting of hundreds of diagnosis codes. I'm intending to reduce these to a broader condition. For example,

`dt <- data.frame(Diagnosis=c("A415","A419","B519","B589","T814"),Broader.Condition=NA)`

Is a snapshot of my current data. I thought I might be able to iterate through each diagnosis code, check if it is one we are interested in, then input the broader diagnosis to the corresponding column, here is my attempt

`for(i in 1:length(dt$Diagnosis)){
    if(dt$Diagnosis[i] == "A415"||"A419"||"B519"||"B589"||"T814"){
      dt$Broader.Condition[i] = "Skull and Face Fractures"}`

However I don't believe i'm using the `||` 'or' statements correctly as it throws

`"Error in dt$Diagnosis[i] == "A415" || "A419" : invalid 'y' type in 'x'||'y'`

Any advice on this or just 'or' statements within loops would be appreciated. I'm going to extend this to each code and its corresponding broader condition using multiple 'if' statements in my 'for' loop.

Comment: The reason you're getting the error is that || and | (and & and &&) require full expressions/logicals on each side. @akrun's answer is best, but to use || you would need `dt$Diagnosis[i] == "A415" || dt$Diagnosis[i] ==  "A419" || dt$Diagnosis[i] == "B519"`

Comment: To add some more details to the difference between & and &&. & will compare all arguments of 2 vectors whilst && will just compare the first element from each vector. Check out the following examples
`c(1,0,1) & c(1,1,1) ;
c(1,0,1) && c(1,1,1) ;
c(1,0,1) && c(0,1,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unbalanced brackets, by the way.  I removed all brackets, as they are useless here.

Way 1:

```
for(i in 1:length(dt$Diagnosis))
    if(dt$Diagnosis[i] == "A415"||dt$Diagnosis[i] == "A419"||dt$Diagnosis[i] == "B519"||dt$Diagnosis[i] == "B589"||dt$Diagnosis[i] == "T814")
      dt$Broader.Condition[i] = "Skull and Face Fractures"
```

Way 2:

```
for(i in 1:length(dt$Diagnosis))
    if(dt$Diagnosis[i] %in% c("A415","A419","B519","B589","T814"))
      dt$Broader.Condition[i] = "Skull and Face Fractures"
```

Way 3 (note: akrun posted a similar solution 4 minutes earlier than I posted my message)

```
is.skull.fractured = dt$Diagnosis %in% c("A415","A419","B519","B589","T814")
dt$Broader.Condition[is.skull.fractured] = "Skull and Face Fractures"
```

Comment: This is perfect, thankyou., I didn't realise that the || parts required full logical statements along with them. Given that there are multiple definitions to add, I'll be using method 2 with multiple if statements.

Answer (score 3):

When there are more than element to compare, it is better to use `%in%` to return a logical `vector`.  Using that, we assign the elements in 'Broader.Condition' to 'Skull and Face Fractures'.

```
dt$Broader.Condition[dt$Diagnosis %in% values] <- "Skull and Face Fractures"
```

where

```
values <- c("A415", "A419", "B519", "B589", "T814")
```

---

If there are more values to be replaced, we can use a key/value dataset

```
kv <- data.frame(Diagnosis = c("A415", "A419", "B519",  "T814", "B589"), 
  Value = c("Skull", "Face", "Skin", "Skull", "Face"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dt$Broader.Condition <- kv$Value[match(dt$Diagnosis, kv$Diagnosis)]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `dt$Broader.Condition <- ifelse(dt$Diagnosis %in% values, "Skull and Face Fractures", ifelse(dt$Diagnosis %in% values2), ...)` ?

Comment: Ofcourse, this is assuming if there are more values to be added to `dt$Broader.Condition`

Comment: @Sumedh  I wouldn't use `ifelse` if there are many values.  Perhaps a key/value pair matching/merging would be more easier

Comment: There are more values to be added, but @user31264's answer also took care of that

Comment: @Rowley058  How is that taking care of it.  I am can only see the `||`

Comment: @akrun, Agreed! Thanks!

Comment: @Rowley058, Just as an FYI, @akrun's suggestion about key/value pair matching/merging would be much more efficient than adding multiple `if` statements

Comment: @akrun, I should have made it more clear, althought I did state that I had hundreds of codes, and also at the end that I was going to extend this to multiple broader diagnoses. My apologies.

I'll be suing user31264's method, way 2 specifically, and use multiple if statements for each broader diagnosis

Comment: @Rowley058  It's okay.  I updated with another approach.  However, you are free to use the `if/else` cumbersome approach.